# Using ArcGIS Marketplace for focussed apps with limited functionality?

Tags: arcgis-market-place

According to the [ArcGIS Marketplace FAQ](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/marketplace/provider/faq.htm):

> All apps in the marketplace must require a named user login.

and

> **Can people who aren't members of an ArcGIS Online organization purchase an app from the marketplace?**
>
> No. The marketplace is for ArcGIS users, so access to apps or data is
>   available exclusively to ArcGIS Online-named users.

According to the [ArcGIS Marketplace Help](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/marketplace/provider/build-apps.htm):

> There are two main requirements for building ArcGIS Marketplace apps:
>
> - Leverage ArcGIS Online subscriptions ...
> - User login with OAuth 2.0 ...

I have an idea for an app that leverages ArcGIS Online subscriptions and requires user login with OAuth 2.0.

I am hoping to bring it to market at a price of about $20 per annum because it is a focussed app targeted at a potentially large but non-traditional market.

However, when I read about named users on the [Identity](http://www.esri.com/products/arcgis-capabilities/identity) page it says that:

> With your identity [(named user credential)], you can access a growing
>   list of standard and premium capabilities:
>
> - Ready-to-Use Apps, App Builders, and Connectors
> - Collector for ArcGIS
> - Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS
> - ArcGIS Open Data (for publishing)
> - Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS (for building apps)
> - ArcGIS Maps for Office
> - ArcGIS Pro

My understanding is that named users have been priced according to the most sophisticated functionality in this list (ArcGIS Pro) when my app would be using only the most basic functionality in this list (Ready-to-Use Apps, App Builders).

Is there a pathway to participate in the ArcGIS Marketplace using named users in the sense of an identity that makes them known to Esri (OAuth 2.0), which leverages ArcGIS Online subscriptions by enabling its credits to be drawn down, but only allows those named users access to very limited functionality at a commensurate price?

I ask because I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section you quoted about access to apps (Collector, ArcGIS Pro, etc) is aimed at org admins, not marketplace providers. Each of those apps is considered an "entitlement"; something all named users have access to simply by having a named user login to ArcGIS Online.

As of today, there is no pricing difference for named users based on their functionality. You could have an ArcGIS Online org with 100 users who all had full admin permissions and you would pay the same per user as an org where they all had view only permissions. The capabilities available to each named user are set by the org administrator. See the documentation on [built-in roles](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/roles.htm) and [configuring custom roles](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/configure-roles.htm) for more detail.

As an app publisher, you control exactly what capabilities are exposed to the users and the org administrator [controls who your application is shared with](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/marketplace/consumer/manage-licenses.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E165F8B84D614A4EA02A08704C5943BE).

In summary, I think you're already on the right path. Take a look at the licensing of some of the other apps in the Marketplace today. For example, [Community Analyst](https://marketplace.arcgis.com/listing.html?id=7b504b19ddbd4f0db06e9a16eebb5efc) is $500 per 5 users. An org admin would purchase the app, then selectively share it with 5 users in their org by putting those users into a group and sharing the app there. Hope that helps.

Comment: It helps but I think you are saying that if I am a user new to the ArcGIS platform then to be able to use just the Community Analyst functionality then I need to become a named user by buying an ArcGIS Pro (as part of ArcGIS for Desktop) license (which if I were a novice user I might never use) before I can unlock Community Analyst for another $100 p.a. per seat.  That seems like a very expensive path to getting access to functionality that has been ostensibly priced at $100 p.a.

Comment: Yes, if you're marketing to users who are new to ArcGIS Online then they'll have to buy a subscription to access your app. The [lowest price plan](https://www.arcgis.com/features/plans/pricing.html) equates to $500/user. That's a fair amount to pay if the only intended use is your app. Side note: each license of ArcGIS Desktop includes 1 named user.
The benefit of the ArcGIS Marketplace is that you're marketing to users who already have an ArcGIS login (and access to capabilities). Have you considered using a [developer plan](https://developers.arcgis.com/features/)?

Comment: I'm fine for my own licensing because I already maintain ArcGIS for Desktop at a Standard level license which gives me a named user and 100 credits.  It is only when I start to think about how someone new to the ArcGIS platform, who is only likely to use a tiny percentage of its functionality, gets authorised to use an app that I develop in a way that splits high volume but small transaction revenue between Esri and I that the Marketplace seems difficult to navigate.

Comment: If you use a developer plan, you are no longer bound to named user logins. You can authenticate them however you choose and use [app login](https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/#app-login) to provide non-named users with access to premium content and services. This wouldn't work well for an app designed to let users work against their own content, but it is a good option for apps that need to otherwise leverage the robust capabilities of ArcGIS Online.

Comment: It would be good if you could [edit] your answer to include something about how/when a [Developer Plan](https://developers.arcgis.com/plans/) could be used in place of named users to open up the ArcGIS Marketplace.  It seems that they may be the missing piece of my understanding which led to my question.